# Jruby extend java class in another directory using Rubymine

Tags: java, ruby, jruby, git-submodules, rubymine

I am somewhat new to RubyMine but here is my problem.  I have a JRUBY Class that I want to extend from a Java class.  My Java class is part of a submodule I have imported using git.  This is my project structure:

```
src --> Submodule --> <Directories> --> ClassIWantToExtend.java
    --> Ruby Code --> <Directories> --> JRubyClassThatExtendsJava.rb
```

However, when using RubyMine I have been unable to figure out how to extend this Java class. It can't seem to find it.  My current class is blank.  This is all I have:

```
require 'java'

class JRubyClassThatExtendsJava
end
```

I have tried using '<' and 'include' but when autofilling RubyMine can't seem to find my Java Class.  I did just add the submodule using a CLI Git Command.  Is it possible I have to add something for RubyMine to see it?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RubyMine, as far as I know (bought a license but never actually used it due this) does not include support for .java (not even a syntax highlighter) - the motivation seems to be that they have a separate product that is a Java IDE. thus this answer is not going to be RubyMine specific :

- first you'll need to compile the `.java` sources and either pack them in a .jar or simply keep in mind what directory the `.class` files are (`javac -d OUT_DIR`)
- than in your `.rb` you can either `require 'path/to/packed.jar'` or simply `$CLASSPATH << 'path/to/classes/OUT_DIR'`

... than you should be able to load the Java class and extend it in Ruby

Comment: IntelliJ Ultimate is not just "Java IDE" -- it supports all other languages via plugins (at no extra cost) including Ruby, Python, PHP. So if you need both -- IntelliJ Ultimate is what you need (note that since it does all languages, it costs more).

Comment: @LazyOne seems a bit off-topic since the question is about RubyMine

Comment: Thank you to both of you.  I would prefer to do this within an IDE if possible.  So I have downloaded the trial of IntelliJ Ultimate and added the Ruby plugin.  @Kares ...both the J-Ruby file and the Java class will be in the same Jar, so I don't want to do it that.  The next idea would be to put the Java Class in the classpath.  I have put it in my module's dependencies... but I still cannot seem to find it.  Any ideas?